# how to install illuminate/mail via composer in Lumen

Tags: laravel, package, composer-php, lumen

A  setting mail-in on `lumen` project, I should install `illuminate\mail` via `composer`, but show me an error:

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages

Comment: Lumen already supports email, you don't have to install anything. [Doc reference](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/6.x/mail)

Comment: Before using Laravel's mail drivers in Lumen, you will need to install the illuminate/mail package via Composer.

Comment: composer require illuminate/mail

Answer (score 1):

You can install through composer using the following command in the terminal:

```
composer require illuminate/mail
```

Make sure you are in the project directory.